# How to leave a mission with your team?

Tags: the-division

If you are in a team and finding a mission too tough, or just want to leave to start over, how do you end the current mission?

So far I have only found one solution which is to leave your team and then create a new team once everyone has left.

The other option, which I've not tried, is to literally run out of the mission. Retrace your steps all the way back to the beginning, but I have no idea if this would work.

The third option is to team wipe (everyone dies), but this just respawns you at the most recent mission checkpoint.

So if you're in a team and are midway through a mission, how do you quit the mission?

Comment: That sounds like you pretty much have it covered. Logging out would do it as well, I imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is possible. However you need to run all the way back to the beginning of the mission, to the start point (with the floating text), and then you'll have the option to reset or leave the mission, but stay in your team.

It's also worth noting that when out of combat, you can fast travel back to the start of the mission.